# Using two future tenses together

Tags: syntax, perfect-tense, future-tense, tenses

I was trying to translate something to Latin, and I ended up writing something that made me feel uncertain.
For the purposes of this question, I stripped all unnecessary content to focus on what puzzles me.

I want to express something something in the direction of "you will sing until you are forgotten".
I want to use the future tense for "you will sing" and I want to phrase "you are forgotten" as *oblivio te sumit*, but the tense of the second part is not as important.
I wrote this:

> *Cantabis donec te sumpserit oblivio.*

The question concerns the tense of *sumere*.
Should it be in the future perfect form *sumpserit*, in the perfect form *sumpsit*, or perhaps in the future form *sumet*?
If many are possible, what is the difference?
Is my original sentence grammatical and meaningful?

Since *cantare* is in the future tense, it feels more natural to use a future tense for *sumere* as well.
But for some reason I like a perfect tense too, as it gives the tone of "you will sing until you have been forgotten".
Changing the exact point in time of the oblivion is fine; I want to explore my (three?) options here for the tense of *sumere*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to add to my answer with a more grammatical explanation if I have time, but for now I can introduce some sample phrases. These examples come from the Lewis & Short entry for [*donec*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddonec):

- Future perfect

  > haud desinam, donec perfecero hoc (Ter. Ph. 2, 3, 73)

  Also:

  > neque defetiscar usque adeo experirier
  >   donec tibi id quod pollicitus sum effecero. (ib. 4, 1, 24)
- Future

  > hic regnabitur ... donec regina sacerdos geminam partu dabit Ilia prolem (Verg. A. 1, 273)

The Vergil example seems most close to yours, since it does not involve a negation or a discrete action. Since Terence is ante-classical, I would recommend the **future as a safer option**, though I have no standing to say whether the future perfect is less correct.

There is a wealth of information about this topic in pg. 680 of Fischer's [*Latin Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gaJIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA680&lpg=PA680).

Comment: Are you still planning to update this answer? No hurry or pressure.

Answer (score 3):

Your specific question allows it, so would you be interested in avoiding the construction with a conjugated verb ? If you are, you might consider a few options, some of which are admittedly arcane and maybe not exactly grammatical (because I'm mostly spitballing here):

- using a perfect tense in the passive voice plus ellipsis of es/eris (of course, this allows freedom between *futurum exactum* and *perfectum*, not *futurum exactum* and *futurum simplex*)

> cantabis donec ab oblivione sumptus [es/eris]

- the *gerundivum*

> cantabis te ab oblivione sumendum

- the *supinum*

> cantabis [te] sumptum ab oblivione

- avoiding a verb form and hence *consecutio temporum* altogether

> cantabis usque (ad/in) oblivionem

Comment: I want to keep *oblivio* as the subject, so these suggestions don't help towards my eventual goal, but the general reminder of workarounds is a welcome one. (+1!) I'm not convinced about the gerundive and the supine (might be fine, but they sound weird to me), but the first and last ones look good to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm becoming less and less sure of their value myself - and their grammaticality, for that matter

Comment: I think examples (2) and (3) change the meaning pretty drastically. I would translate: (2) "you will sing about yourself needing to be..." (3) this wouldn't be a supine but rather a past participle: "you will sing about how you were taken...